# Semantics vs Grammar

Tags: meaning, grammar

I know that in a sentence like, "I went to the movies again." again would modify the verb went. Although, the actual meaning of the sentence is that the whole action of going to the movies was done a second time, right?

Comment: Why do you think  *again* **doesn't** modify the clause *I went to the movies*?

Comment: According to all pages on the internet, the adverb would just modify the verb. That is just the way grammar works as opposed to semantics. Semantically, it would modify the entire action.

Comment: Isn't modifying the verb semantically equivalent to modifying the whole statement in this case? The only thing that is repeated is the action.

Answer (score -1):

The actual meaning *does* convey the action being repeated again. But adding **once** before again will leave no ambiguity as it will precisely indicate the second time you are going to the movies. 
Hope this helps.